# Apache Camel Rest Service and Consumer

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

I am trying to learn Apache camel, I have simple scenario in mind.
I have to host a simple rest service,

`curl -s "http://localhost:8080/camel-rest-jpa/books/123"`

this service will invoke another service `"http://localhost:8080/some/booking/?name=123` (ideally I want to invoke external service on on same app, for simplicity I have done this).

The code for service is here:

> https://github.com/am431/camel-poc

This is throwing

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri: /camel-rest-jpa/books/123/books/123?name=123. If you are forwarding/bridging http endpoints, then enable the bridgeEndpoint option on the endpoint: http4://localhost:8080/some/b

I am not sure why ...

This code works with file connector:
`

```
from("file:data/inbox?noop=true")
    .log("${body}")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY,simple("name=${body}"))
    .enrich("http4://localhost:8080/some/booking/")
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .log("${body}")
    .to("file:data/outbox");`

    while this doesn't

`rest("/books").description("Books REST service")
    .get("/{id}").description("The list of all the books")
    .route().routeId("books-api")
    .log("${header.id}")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY,simple("name=${header.id}"))
    .enrich("http4://localhost:8080/some/booking/")
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .log("${body}")
    .bean(Database.class, "findAll")
    .endRest();
```

`

Comment: as you can see from exception logs, Camel is using your original uri(with which you called rest /books) to make another request through http4 component. I think you will have to overwrite Exchange properties of HTTP_URL and URI in a processor to make it work.

Comment: hear is log file https://github.com/am431/camel-poc/blob/master/log.txt

Comment: Thanks @Sikorski Let me try that.

Comment: @Sikorski I have added `.process( e -> e.getIn().getHeaders().clear())` after `.log("${header.id}")` method it is working fine. It is kinda work around. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: well the exact behavior can be explained by Camel experts Claus and William, maybe you can ask this question on camel nabble forum. Can you also try with sending the exchange to a different seda or direct route after receiving rest call, that may take care of the extra processor.

Comment: Instead of using processor, then clean, refer this link
http://camel.apache.org/how-to-remove-the-http-protocol-headers-in-the-camel-message.html to remove headers. Removing the headers before calling another HTTP endpoint is kind-of needed, if you haven't specified "bridgeEndpoint"